# How to add JSON data associated with each link onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

At first, it worked. But this code is not gonna work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an actual snippet that works (your JSON is invalid and it won't load data.json as SO doesn't know what that is). To be able to further help you, I need to know what exactly you mean by href? I will modify this answer once I understand exactly what you are asking. You already have a click event for when you select an auto-complete live search entry, why not just hook into that? Or are you expecting to do a page re-direct after clicking the live-search entry?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
  });

  $('#search').keyup(function() {
  
    $('#result').html('');
    $('#state').val('');
    var searchField = $('#search').val();
    var expression = new RegExp(searchField, "i");

    $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/znh29', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        if (value.name.search(expression) != -1 ||
          value.location.search(expression) != -1) {
          $('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"><img src="' + value.image + '" height="40" width="40" class="img-thumbnail" /> ' + value.name + ' | <span class="text-muted">' + value.location + '</span></li>');
        }
      });
    });

  });

  $('#result').on('click', 'li', function() {
    var click_text = $(this).text().split('|');
    click_text = $.trim(click_text[0]);
    $('#search').val(click_text);
    $("#result").html('');
    // YOUR CUSTOM URL HERE:
    window.location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com/?data=" + click_text;
  });

});
```

```css
#result {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 870px;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  z-index: 1001;
}

.link-class:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Webslesson Tutorial | Search HTML Table Data by using JQuery</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="container" style="width:900px;">
    <h2 align="center">JSON Live Data Search using Ajax JQuery</h2>
    <h3 align="center">Employee Data</h3>
    <br /><br />
    <div align="center">
      <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search Employee Details" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <ul class="list-group" id="result"></ul>
    <br />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I meant it should redirect when i click on it. However, that's not working at the moment. Autocomplete is working properly but i search angel lewis for example, it appears but not redirecting when i click on it.

Comment: I've update the snippet, please see if that is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the code below with the one mentioned in your question.

```
$('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"><img src="'+value.image+'" height="40" width="40" class="img-thumbnail" /> '+value.name+' | <a class="text-muted" href="'+value.location+'">'+value.location +'</a></li>');
```

I replaced the span tag with anchor tag and you could notice the href links work when clicked on it. hope this helps you fix the problem. This will show only the location as clickable link.

If you want to redirected to the href location when clicking either name or location shown then I would suggest use below code for replace. This will show both name and location as clickable link.

```
$('#result').append('<li class="list-group-item link-class"><img src="'+value.image+'" height="40" width="40" class="img-thumbnail" /> <a class="text-muted" href="'+value.location+'">'+value.name+' | '+value.location +'</a></li>');
```

To Make li onclick event to redirect to href location use the below code.

```
$('#result').append('<a class="text-muted" href="'+value.location+'"><li class="list-group-item link-class"><img src="'+value.image+'" height="40" width="40" class="img-thumbnail" /> '+value.name+' | '+value.location +'</li></a>');
```

Change the css for name and location to below so that it looks like plain text and not anchor links.

```
 a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
 }
```

Comment: It works, but how can i do on background (clickable) ?

Comment: You want to redirect to the href location when clicked on <li>? Is my understanding right?

Comment: Ohh, my bad sorry about that, Your code is working. Thank you soo much.

Comment: Updated the answer as per your requirement. When you click <li> on background it will redirect to the href location. Hope this works for you. Can you upvote for the answer if it works.

Comment: I can't vote right now, it says. Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.